# Insert multipal checked value in multiple row in mysql with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have face a problem. I want to insert multi checked value in multi row in mysql data table.... But When i insert it store all in one row...
How can i fix it...
My Model is:

```
    public function apply_for_work_check()
    {
    $variable = $this->input->post('Infrashtructure');
     $data = array(
    'id' =>null,
    'works_id' => 1,
    'infrashtructure_name' => json_encode(implode(",", $variable)),
    );
    $result=$this->db->insert('infrashtructure_txn_info',$data);
    if($result)
    {
    return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
    return FALSE;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Do `insert` for each value in `$variable`  not once with `implode()`

Comment: Please show the content of `$variable` using `print_r($variable)`

Answer (score 1):

Change your method as below:

```
public function apply_for_work_check()
{
    $variable = $this->input->post('Infrashtructure');
    foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
        $data = array(
            'id'                   => null,
            'works_id'             => 1,
            'infrashtructure_name' => $value,
        );
        $result = $this->db->insert('infrashtructure_txn_info', $data);
    }
    if ($result) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function apply_for_work_check()
{
 $result=array();
 $variable = $this->input->post('Infrashtructure');
 foreach($variable as $var){
     $data = array('id' =>null,'works_id' => 1,
                   'infrashtructure_name' => json_encode($var));
     $result[]=$this->db->insert('infrashtructure_txn_info',$data);
 }

 if(count($result)==array_sum($result)) {#checks if all was TRUE
   return TRUE;
 } else {
   return FALSE;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = explode(",", $variable);
```

After this.

```
'infrashtructure_name' => json_encode(implode(",", $data))
```